# how to index inside onclick in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have simple 5 buttons like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-success">Button 1</button>
<button class="btn btn-success">Button 2</button>
<button class="btn btn-success">Button 3</button>
<button class="btn btn-success">Button 4</button>
<button class="btn btn-success">Button 5</button>
```

I have this corresponding javascript code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
    var button = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
    for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
        button[i].onclick = function(){
            console.log("button " + i)
        }
    }
},false)
```

I want to index i for button array inside onclick, for purpose such as `button[i].classList.add("something"`), I don't want to use "this" like `this.classList.add("something")`. How can I do that?, thanks

Comment: Simple solution, use forEach instead of `for-loop`. Value of `i` is not scoped in for-loop hence you will always get the latest value of `i` in callback function.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `this`? Do you need a dynamic class name using the index or something?

Comment: You need to either set it as data in the HTML element or loop the buttons and create a different listener for each button passing the index, something like this `Array.from(btns).map((btn, index) => { 
btn.addEventListener("click", () => { myClickHandler(index); }) })`

Comment: @Rayon I can't call `button.forEach(myFunction);` although button is a list/array

Comment: @dangthaii - You can use ```Array.from(button).forEach```

Comment: very well, thanks Rayon

Answer (score 0):

try to

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".clickme");
var count = 0;

buttons.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const index =   Array.from(buttons).indexOf(e.target);
    alert(index);
    });
});
```

I found it on https://www.mejorcodigo.com/p/20019.html